# Regex. How to remove multiple occurence of 'u' if it's befoure some symbol

Tags: python, regex

I have this string:

```
p = "{u'symbols': [], u'user_mentions': [{u'indices': [0, 9], u'id': 1425561991, u'id_str': u'1425561991', u'name': u'h u2661', u'screen_name': u'oppsli4m'}, {u'indices': [10, 23], u'id': 27260086, u'id_str': u'27260086', u'name': u'Justin Bieber', u'screen_name': u'justinbieber'}], u'hashtags': [], u'urls': []}"
```

As you can see I have a "Unicode character" in front of every string. So I want to remove every single `u` if it is in front of `'`.

I tried :

```
vals = re.split('u', p)
```

And some other variations of this expression. But had no luck.

I hope my question is clear, but just in case , the result that I want to get should look something like this:

```
"{'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [{'indices': [0,9], 'id': 124......"
```

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: FWIW, you can evaluate this string directly into python objects using `ast.literal_eval` for python2.x and python3.3+

Comment: How did you get to this string?  This looks like a `print`ed/`str()`ed dictionary, which you'd probably have an easier time working with as serialized data if you used `json.dumps()` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
import re
print re.sub(r"u('\w)", r"\1", p)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's very close to what I was looking for

Answer (score 6):

No. You do not want to do this.

You should not be passing that string round in the first place. I don't know where it came from, but it seems like someone has just called `str` on a list. Instead, you should use a proper serialization method, ie JSON.

Comment: Exactly, but I think the only way to store json or yaml or other serialization methods in RDS is to use TEXT field, correct me if I'm wrong pls. And plus some people on twitter like to use some non ASCII characters and weird symbols. ))

Comment: What type are you wanting to use?  You don't have many options for arbitrary serialized data other than text, and if the data isn't arbitrary, you'd probably have a better time with a more robust schema that allows you to more fully normalize your data.

Comment: That's a good point. And I agree with that, but, in my situation, I don't have a lot of time on doing this. So I just need to do it in a little bit dirty way, but fast.

Comment: `json.dumps(dictionary)`.  Quick and dirty.